# Aligning Content in Table - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to align my content to the right side of the image.

The website is: https://thehayexchange.co.uk

You can see the thumbnails are to the left of the listing, but the text is split. Any idea how I can have it so that all text flows on the right of the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to edit the HTML, you can do this with Flexbox.

You'll need to change your HTML structure so that the text is all inside one container, something like:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="image">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="text">
        <div class="first-text-block"></div>
        <div class="second-text-block"></div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

Then align them with Flexbox:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

Comment: Also if you use Flexbox, float doesn't apply, so you can remove the 'fix-float' span.